# Android - Getting "Could not get currentAdManager"

Tags: android, crash, admob

I'm trying to add ads (AdMob) into my Android app. App works fine, ads shows normally, but everytime I click on ad, application crashes and LogCat writes `E/Ads(1356): Could not get currentAdManager.`
Do somebody have any clue what causes this error message? How to deal with it?
(Google didn't gave me useful answer)
Thanks

---

Log:

```
06-25 20:40:52.257: D/dalvikvm(1288): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 81K, 9% free 2599K/2828K, paused 265ms, total 272ms
06-25 20:40:52.417: D/dalvikvm(1288): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 8% free 2904K/3140K, paused 39ms, total 40ms
06-25 20:40:52.718: D/dalvikvm(1288): GC_CONCURRENT freed 326K, 15% free 2989K/3508K, paused 76ms+6ms, total 126ms
06-25 20:40:52.718: D/dalvikvm(1288): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 38ms
06-25 20:40:52.737: I/dalvikvm-heap(1288): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.666MB for 635812-byte allocation
06-25 20:40:52.806: D/dalvikvm(1288): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 13% free 3609K/4132K, paused 39ms, total 41ms
06-25 20:40:53.657: E/ActivityThread(1288): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
06-25 20:40:53.898: I/SQLiteAssetHelper(1288): successfully opened database dbSlabiky
06-25 20:40:54.303: D/dalvikvm(1288): GC_CONCURRENT freed 234K, 10% free 3801K/4184K, paused 72ms+112ms, total 381ms
06-25 20:40:54.667: D/libEGL(1288): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
06-25 20:40:54.717: D/(1288): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a2757a0, tid 1288
06-25 20:40:54.727: D/dalvikvm(1288): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads1347299026.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
06-25 20:40:54.756: D/libEGL(1288): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
06-25 20:40:54.778: D/libEGL(1288): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
06-25 20:40:55.007: W/EGL_emulation(1288): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-25 20:40:55.046: D/OpenGLRenderer(1288): Enabling debug mode 0
06-25 20:40:55.208: D/dalvikvm(1288): DexOpt: --- END 'ads1347299026.jar' (success) ---
06-25 20:40:55.208: D/dalvikvm(1288): DEX prep '/data/data/eu.kubacech.partybomba/cache/ads1347299026.jar': unzip in 20ms, rewrite 480ms
06-25 20:40:55.627: I/Ads(1288): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"session_id":"2499001843917976796","seq_num":"1","slotname":"a151c9c1b86a5ba","u_w":320,"msid":"eu.kubacech.partybomba","cap":"m,a","adtest":"on","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","bas_off":0,"net":"ed","app_name":"1.android.eu.kubacech.partybomba","hl":"cs","smart_w":"full","gnt":3,"carrier":"310260","u_audio":4,"kw":[],"u_sd":1.5,"simulator":1,"ms":"P7OMFYsqAIwBe-sGkFp1MsUK_gzXfFRPJ_SPHwO_e22gvp5MXZMJSIZ0u9Tbs7iT3_2fudRHOrOWIpkc9l4iOEQ-1KbzXhit13md58Nnd8Ta-U9YPemBBJz_xKWCD-t_iwJKrqCuwxvQM3CyWncui-rfhXVdKCg6vYC5Ea2lsCodagdZOIF2Ubvv4mjrM1y3JCA3B8rhSU7GP3vlj449JcVMPyCwXdLUMkzKY60ZABOAaE0Fjqk4graEVk_lXYoEfdkLBylQlWPjUIR62olkyPFKGkarCv4r4BYZ03u_68yUV0tcDaF1hKoWLB958zBAPqulO5SRgR2d0vJy1nusrg","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"smart_h":"auto","ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":1,"y":800,"x":0,"width":480},"u_h":533,"pt":1,"bas_on":0,"ptime":0});</script></head><body></body></html>
06-25 20:40:58.538: I/Ads(1288): Received ad url: <url: "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=0&session_id=2499001843917976796&seq_num=1&u_w=320&msid=eu.kubacech.partybomba&cap=m%2Ca&adtest=on&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&bas_off=0&net=ed&app_name=1.android.eu.kubacech.partybomba&hl=cs&smart_w=full&gnt=3&carrier=310260&u_audio=4&kw&u_sd=1.5&ms=P7OMFYsqAIwBe-sGkFp1MsUK_gzXfFRPJ_SPHwO_e22gvp5MXZMJSIZ0u9Tbs7iT3_2fudRHOrOWIpkc9l4iOEQ-1KbzXhit13md58Nnd8Ta-U9YPemBBJz_xKWCD-t_iwJKrqCuwxvQM3CyWncui-rfhXVdKCg6vYC5Ea2lsCodagdZOIF2Ubvv4mjrM1y3JCA3B8rhSU7GP3vlj449JcVMPyCwXdLUMkzKY60ZABOAaE0Fjqk4graEVk_lXYoEfdkLBylQlWPjUIR62olkyPFKGkarCv4r4BYZ03u_68yUV0tcDaF1hKoWLB958zBAPqulO5SRgR2d0vJy1nusrg&isu=B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&smart_h=auto&u_h=533&bas_on=0&ptime=0&u_so=p&imbf=%40installed_markets%40&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=0&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a14f85cda644e1d&kw_type=broad&gsb=3g&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=49" type: "admob" afmaNotifyDt: "null" activationOverlayUrl: "null" useWebViewLoadUrl: "false">
06-25 20:40:58.637: I/Ads(1288): Ad url modified to http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=0&session_id=2499001843917976796&seq_num=1&u_w=320&msid=eu.kubacech.partybomba&cap=m%2Ca&adtest=on&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&bas_off=0&net=ed&app_name=1.android.eu.kubacech.partybomba&hl=cs&smart_w=full&gnt=3&carrier=310260&u_audio=4&kw&u_sd=1.5&ms=P7OMFYsqAIwBe-sGkFp1MsUK_gzXfFRPJ_SPHwO_e22gvp5MXZMJSIZ0u9Tbs7iT3_2fudRHOrOWIpkc9l4iOEQ-1KbzXhit13md58Nnd8Ta-U9YPemBBJz_xKWCD-t_iwJKrqCuwxvQM3CyWncui-rfhXVdKCg6vYC5Ea2lsCodagdZOIF2Ubvv4mjrM1y3JCA3B8rhSU7GP3vlj449JcVMPyCwXdLUMkzKY60ZABOAaE0Fjqk4graEVk_lXYoEfdkLBylQlWPjUIR62olkyPFKGkarCv4r4BYZ03u_68yUV0tcDaF1hKoWLB958zBAPqulO5SRgR2d0vJy1nusrg&isu=B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&smart_h=auto&u_h=533&bas_on=0&ptime=0&u_so=p&imbf=8008&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=0&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a14f85cda644e1d&kw_type=broad&gsb=3g&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=49
06-25 20:40:58.647: I/Ads(1288): Request scenario: Online server request.
06-25 20:41:00.546: D/webviewglue(1288): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a279ea8
06-25 20:41:00.597: I/Ads(1288): onReceiveAd()
06-25 20:41:00.927: D/dalvikvm(1288): GC_CONCURRENT freed 288K, 10% free 4017K/4456K, paused 8ms+13ms, total 199ms
06-25 20:41:00.939: D/webviewglue(1288): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a2543b8
06-25 20:41:01.087: D/TilesManager(1288): Starting TG #0, 0x2a1bac28
06-25 20:41:07.897: I/AndroidRuntime(1288): VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
06-25 20:41:08.337: E/Trace(1356): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-25 20:41:08.447: E/Ads(1356): Could not get currentAdManager.
```

Manifest (permissions granted):

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Layout:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="***"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" >

    </com.google.ads.AdView>
```